# Plupload Filters issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, plupload

I am trying to use filters with plupload like this:

```
filters: [
            { title: "RAR Files", extensions: "rar" }

        ],
```

but when I browse for files it shows all types of files; however when I replace rar with zip it only shows zip files; I tried reading about the issue and read that it is non-mime-registered file extension error? but I think rar is a well common extension no? any one explain it to me please...
Here is a full code demo http://jsfiddle.net/VjeTk/58/

Is it also possible to force the browse dialog to always show all file extensions even though filters are specified...

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a MIME thing; I found an answer on Plupload; if anyone faces a similar issue.
Until a proper resolution is put; you can use either methods mentioned in the post.

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=9604#p9604

Answer (score 1):

This behavior depends on the runtime in use. The HTML5 runtime suffers from this issue whereas Flash and SilverLight do not. So, to minimize the impact of the issue, you can use them in priority:

```
new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'silverlight,flash,html5,gears,browserplus',
    filters: [ { title: "RAR Files", extensions: "rar" } ],
    ...
});
```

HTML5 may still be used, but at least Flash and SilverLight will be favored when available.

Comment: I am doing just that really, thnx.